# Tkinter Text not displaying

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, tkinter

I'm sorry if that this is my second post in such a short period of time but I don't understand what is happening.

This is my code so far:

```
def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        hours = int(self.hour.get())
        minutes = int(self.minutes.get())
        seconds = int(self.seconds.get())

        if seconds == 0:
            if minutes != 0:
                seconds += 59
                minutes -= 1
            elif minutes == 0:
                if hours != 0:
                    minutes += 59
                    seconds += 59
                    hours -= 1
                else:
                    self.timerLab.configure(text="Times Up!")   

        else:
            self.timerLab.configure(text="Time Remaining: %d:%d:%d " % (hours,minutes,seconds))
            seconds -= 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

so this is a countdown timer that i have so far and i do not understand why seconds isn't updating. As far as my logic is concerned, if seconds -= 1 then it should take one and as it continues through the loop it should update. Am i right, or am I just completely being stupid and missing the obvious?

If any more of the code is needed please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `seconds -= 1` at the end of the function is not going to do anything because you reset it on the next call to the value in the countdown timer. So you are basically setting the countdown timer to the exact same thing every time. Move that line above
`self.timerLab.configure(text="Time Remaining: %d:%d:%d " % (hours,minutes,seconds))`

And see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why it stops at 1 for seconds?

Comment: it just stops at 1 second. It doesn't change minutes or hours, it just counts down to 1 second and then stops. Any idea?

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie Could be to do with your `if seconds == 0`. I'm not fully sure though

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems here:

- The same seconds value is always used: You decrement it, but the next time you get the same value from the `Entry` widget.
- `after` is only called in the `else` block, so when `seconds == 0` it is not going to execute the method again.
- The argument `remaining` is always None, since you use the reference to the function without passing arguments.

For the last problem, a quick fix would be change the last statement to `self.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown(remaining))`, but there is an even better solution:

- Calculate the remaning total of seconds, and store this number as a variable.
- Call in a separate method `after`, and decrement there the variable used to represent the remaining seconds.
- Use [`divmod()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) to easily conver the number of seconds to the format `"h:m:s"`.

The final result might look like this:

```
def start_countdown(self):
    hours = int(self.hour.get())
    minutes = int(self.minutes.get())
    seconds = int(self.seconds.get())
    self.remaining = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    self.countdown()
def countdown(self):
    if self.remaining == 0:
        self.timerLab.configure(text="Times Up!")
    else:
        m, s = divmod(self.remaining, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        self.timerLab.configure(text="Time Remaining: %d:%d:%d " % (h, m, s))
        self.remaining -= 1
        self.master.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

Comment: I managed to fix the time stopping at 1 second. As for the remaining, that was due to me editing and trying stuff out and forgetting to remove it. It is no longer in my code, I am sorry for not mentioning :c. Thankyou though and you have helped me fix the second issue :)